# Add a new item to a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, items

How do I add an item to an existing dictionary in Python? For example, given:

```
default_data = {
    'item1': 1,
    'item2': 2,
}
```

I want to add a new item such that:

```
default_data = default_data + {'item3': 3}
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: `default_data['item3'] = 3` isn't an option?

Comment: @machine yearning: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers

Comment: i cant believe this inline solution hasn't been posted yet. We can use `{ **default_data, 'item3':3}` which returns the updated array. Very useful for lambda functions and list comprehensions.  (requires [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) (Python 3.5))

Comment: @GlabbichRulz: your solution is exactly the elegant approach I was hoping to find here - would you care to turn your comment into an answer so I can upvote it ? would also get me a direct link I can save for future reference...

Comment: @ssc i am afraid i can't do that, as the question is closed and accepts no further answers. You can use this link though to refer to my comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416131/add-a-new-item-to-a-dictionary-in-python?noredirect=1#comment97082105_6416131

Answer (score 1370, accepted):

```
default_data['item3'] = 3
```

Easy as py.

Another possible solution:

```
default_data.update({'item3': 3})
```

which is nice if you want to insert multiple items at once.

Comment: Sorry for the thread necro, but is there any reason to prefer one method over the other when adding one item?

Comment: @Warrick there's absolutely no difference except for personal taste. Personally I find the first to be a little more intuitive for just one item.

Comment: which is faster?

Comment: @user3067923 This is pure conjecture but I *imagine* that the first one would be marginally faster since it's mutating the dict in place, whereas the second one has to create a temporary dict, then mutate, then garbage collect the temporary dict. I'd need to benchmark it to say definitively.

Comment: @ChrisEberle and either should be O(1), or at least quite close to it, is that right?

Comment: @user3067923 even if it is O(n), how many items can your dictionary possibly have for it to matter? If it is that many, wouldn't a list and indexes be a better structure?

Comment: @ArthurTarasov forgive the snark but what exactly do you think a hash map is? Under the hood it *is* a "list and an index". That's the whole point of using one -- to abstract that away and focus on application logic. I'll grant you that there are other kinds of indices (e.g. B-Tree) -- but they're all better than O(n). If you're writing O(n) lookup procedures, I don't envy the people who have to use your code...

Comment: @Warrick - I had to use 2nd answer as it was within the list comprehension and I was unable to use '=' in it

Comment: Direct set value `default_data['item3'] = 3` doesn't work for generic dictionary `typing.Dict`, anyone know why ?

Answer (score 96):

It can be as simple as:

```
default_data['item3'] = 3
```

As [Chris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416131/python-add-new-item-to-dictionary/6416142#6416142) says, you can use [update](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) to add more than one item.  An example:

```
default_data.update({'item4': 4, 'item5': 5})
```

Please see the documentation about [dictionaries as data structures](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and [dictionaries as built-in types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

Comment: Useful for knowing that you can do multiple items in an update.

Answer (score 26):

It occurred to me that you may have actually be asking how to implement the `+` operator for dictionaries, the following seems to work:

```
>>> class Dict(dict):
...     def __add__(self, other):
...         copy = self.copy()
...         copy.update(other)
...         return copy
...     def __radd__(self, other):
...         copy = other.copy()
...         copy.update(self)
...         return copy
... 
>>> default_data = Dict({'item1': 1, 'item2': 2})
>>> default_data + {'item3': 3}
{'item2': 2, 'item3': 3, 'item1': 1}
>>> {'test1': 1} + Dict(test2=2)
{'test1': 1, 'test2': 2}
```

Note that this is more overhead then using `dict[key] = value` or `dict.update()`, so I would recommend against using this solution unless you intend to create a new dictionary anyway.

Comment: If you don't want to implement your own operators, you can also do `dict(default_data.items() + {'item3': 3}.items())`

Comment: @Pakman's comment doesn't work in Python3 (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361510/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-dict-items-and-dict-items/13361547#13361547)

Comment: For Python 3, a quick fix to still use @Pakman comment is to cast the output of `dict.items()` in a `list` as follows: `dict(list(default_data.items()) + list({'item3': 3}.items()))`, or even use the more idomatic: `{**default_data, **{'item3': 3}}`