# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_items' and 'dict_items'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to sum two dictionaries like that:

```
my_new_dict = dict(my_existing_dict.items() + my_new_dict.items())
```

but recieve error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_items' and 'dict_items'
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: Sidenote: If you want to iterate over two dictionaries, and you know they have unique keys (or it doesn't matter if you process the same key twice), consider using itertools.chain(dict_a, dict_b)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In python3, `dict.items()` returns an object with type `dict_items` which apparently can't be added.  (in python 2, it returned a `list` which could be added).

An alternative way to add a pair of dictionaries which works on py2k and py3k:

```
d = dict1.copy()
d.update(dict2)
```

Of course, there's some ambiguity about what you want to happen in the case of key collisions.  e.g. if both dicts have `key1`, whose `key1` should be preserved in the output?  Or should you use some combination of both of their values?  In the latter case, you'll probably want something from the `collections` module (either `defaultdict` or `Counter`)

Comment: @mgilson: I think that `dict.items()` in 3+ is equivalent to `dict.iteritems()` in 2.6, that is, it's an iterator.

Comment: @PierreGM No, it returns a dictionary view, which is a set-like container (see my answer).

Answer (score 73):

As of Python 3.9 ([PEP 584](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/) in particular), dicts gains union (`|`) and update (`|=`) operations just like sets, so that becomes the "one true way" to achieve what you are looking for.

```
d3 = d1 | d2
```

With the second dictionary taking precedence in the case of key collision.

That PEP lists the other options available in earlier Python versions, which all have their downsides. If you are up to [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) (Python 3.5), I would recommend using:

```
{**d1, **d2}
```

This is unpacking both dictionaries into a new one, resulting in a union.

One problem is the behavior you want is ambiguous - dictionaries can't have duplicate keys, so it is unclear what you want to happen if both contain the same key. The spec is explicit about what should happen when using this method:

> In dictionaries, later values will always override earlier ones

If you want the reverse behaviour, you can simply swap the order of the dictionaries in the literal.

Your approach doesn't work because [dictionary views are set-like](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), so they don't have addition implemented.

What you probably want is the [union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union): `d1.items() | d2.items()`, which will give you a set of tuples of `(key, value)`. If you then pass it to `dict()` and there are duplicates, the "last" value will be the one used, however sets (unlike the views themselves) are unordered, so there is no guarantee about which item will end up "first" in the combined set, meaning that which one "wins" will be arbitrary.

So, in short, as long as order/duplicate selection isn't important:

```
dict(d1.items() | d2.items())
```

In Python 2, `dict.items()` simply returns a `list`, where your approach will work.

Comment: When I try this I get: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

Comment: With Python 3.6.1, I noticed if an item is in both `d1` and `d2`, it seems `dict(d1.items() | d2.items())` results in *d1*'s items taking effect in case of duplicates, which is not what I expected. `dict(list(d1.items()) + list(d2.items()))` behaves as I expect, with `d2` winning in case of duplicates.

Comment: @erwaman Yes, sets are unordered, while dictionaries are (now) ordered. My wording was misleading because "last" doesn't mean much when sets are ordered arbitrarily. If you want to preserve order, you indeed need to use an ordered collection like a list (at a small additional cost of constructing them).

Comment: @erwaman See my latest edit for an updated approach I think is the best option in all cases.

Comment: Maybe you can also opt for:

`{**dict(item for item in original_dict.items() if item[0] not in updating_dict),**updating_dict}`

Comment: @eliax1996 That seems like a much more complicated and likely slower & less memory efficient operation, could you explain why you think that's a better option in any situation? As far as I can see, checking if the values are in the second dict is pointless here, they would be replaced anyway, but your version builds an extra dict.

Comment: probably a bad idea, but I found it more explicit rather than relying on the fact that other devs understand the default behaviour

Answer (score 15):

Another approach to the other suggested answers is:

`dict(list(d1.items()) + list(d2.items()))`

If there are keys present in both `d1` and `d2`, the value in `d2` will be used in the final dictionary.

Comment: Must be new, doesn't work in 3.5.2 but works in 3.6.9. Wish they would just add the common sense syntax of dictN.items() + dictN.items()...

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned `ChainMap`.

```py
from collections import ChainMap

dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
dict2 = {'c': 3, 'd': 4}

combined = ChainMap(dict1, dict2)

print(combined['a']) # Output: 1
print(combined['c']) # Output: 3
```

From the documentation:

> It is often much faster than creating a new dictionary and running multiple update() calls.

It will also preserve order if that's important.