# PubNub Message Ecryption

Tags: python, list, pubnub

Fair warning, I am not a programmer and doing this more as a hobby. Thank you for taking your time to review this and providing suggestions.

I have a List in python: [60.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 347.0, 30.0, 29.0, 1.0] and would like to publish to pubnub with encryption. I have already manage to publish without encryption.

Works:

```
    msg = {"freq" : modbusRead[0],
           "voltage" : modbusRead[1],
           "rpm" : modbusRead[2]
           }

    readSecret = pubnub.publish().channel(CHANNEL).message(msg).pn_async(publish_callback)
```

Doesn't Work:

```
     msg = {"freq" : modbusRead[0],
           "voltage" : modbusRead[1],
           "rpm" : modbusRead[2]
           }

    secretMsg = pubnub.encrypt("RandomCipherKey", msg)

    readSecret = pubnub.publish().channel(CHANNEL).message(secretMsg).pn_async(publish_callback)
```

I get following error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'bytes'

Comment: Hey Rjindner, I'm from PubNub. This doesn't look like PN error but just did search on your error: *"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'bytes"* and there is [an SO thread on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361510/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-dict-items-and-dict-items/13361547). Hope that works for you. If not, let me know.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you try to pass `dict` into method, which expected it to be `bytes`.
Method signature explained [here](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/python/api-reference/misc#methods-3) and usage example shows right below:

```
payload_to_encrypt = b'knights_who_say_ni'
encrypted_payload = pubnub.encrypt("test_cipher_key", payload_to_encrypt)
```

Also, if there is no plans to send push notifications from Python client, it is possible to configure that all data sent / received will be encrypted / decrypted using same token (in this case you don't have to deal with data serialisation for `encrypt` method).
Check `cipher_key` in [PNConfiguration](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/python/api-reference/configuration#methods) object.

Comment: Thank you, it worked very well. I end up encrypting whole message.