# How to add new objects to nested dictionary?

Tags: python, nested

Given the below object, how to add a new city "losangeles" in "california"? Given a country, state, city and attributes for the city, how can I update the object? (I am pretty new to python)

```
myplaces = {
  "unitedstates": {
    "california": {
      "sanfrancisco": {
        "description": "Tech heaven",
        "population": 1234,
        "keyplaces": ["someplace1",
          "someplace2"]
      }
    }
  },
  "india": {
    "karnataka": {
      "bangalore": {
        "description": "IT hub of India",
        "population": 12345,
        "keyplaces": ["jpnagar",
          "brigade"]
      },
      "mysore": {
        "description": "hostoric place",
        "population": 12345,
        "keyplaces": ["mysorepalace"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried adding elements as below (like how it is done in PHP):

```
myplaces['unitedstates']['california']['losangeles']['description'] = 'Entertainment'
```

Edit:
This is not a duplicate. I am looking for a generic way to add items.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python add new item to dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416131/python-add-new-item-to-dictionary)

Comment: please next time add error message to your post

Answer (score 3):

You've almost got it -

```
myplaces['unitedstates']['california']['losangeles'] = {'description':'Entertainment'}
```

Comment: of course this all depends on what `myplaces` contains, so it's not a *generic* solution.

Comment: What if I need to add a new state 'Michigan'? `myplaces['unitedstates']['michigan']['annarbour'] = {'description':'Cold place'}` doesn't work right?

Comment: Correct, you'd have to do something like:
`myplaces['unitedstates']['michigan'] = {} `
first.

Comment: So I need to add a check at each level?

Comment: you want something like `addcity(myplaces, ('unitedstates', 'michigan', 'annarbour'), {.....});` and then in the implementation use a loop and create the "nodes" if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a tree using a dictionary with a default value of a tree:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict

>>> def tree():
...     return defaultdict(tree)


>>> myplaces = tree()
>>> myplaces['unitedstates']['california']['losangeles']['description'] = 'Entertainment'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
myplaces['unitedstates']['california']['losangeles']={}
myplaces['unitedstates']['california']['losangeles']['description']='Entertainment'
```