# Comparing Python Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I created two dictionaries. Each is based on a different query of the same database. There is a key and four fields from the database in each dictionary. I want to find all rows of dict_x that are in are in dict_y.

```
 for row in dict_x:
    if dict_y.values() not in dict_x.values():
         del dict_x[row]

print 'Length dict_x', len(dict_x)
```

This returns the error

```
TypeError: 'type' object does not support item deletion
```

Comment: What do you mean by "row"? Dictionaries don't have rows. They have keys and values.

Comment: Also, you're comparing `dict_y.values()` with `dict_x.values()`.  This is comparing the entire dictionary's values on each iteration - surely not what you want

Comment: By row i mean dictionary item-- I used the word row because the dictionaries were formed from SQL queries.

Comment: won't the dictionary size change during iteration here or am I missing something

Comment: So if the values of a key/row of `dict_x` are in `dict_y` then you want to remove the `key` from `dict_x`?

Comment: `if dict_y.values() not in dict_x.values()` should likely be replaced with `if dict_x[row] not in dict_y.values()`

Comment: so if it's a list of dictionary you code looks more or less good, you are doing del dict_x[row] but you can't pass the row, you need pass the row index; but be careful, you are deleting from the same list that you are iteration so it will cause the jump of a line, because if you delete row 2, row 3 become row 2 and next iteration you will lose it because next iteration will be on row 3

Comment: I want rows with the sames values, their keys will be different.

Comment: I would also be okay with creating a new dictionary with the output.

Comment: I was just also having issues with appending these "rows" to a new dict.

Comment: give example input and output in your questions so as to make it easier for the ones who answer

Answer (score 0):

The steps to solve the  problem would be to

> 1. Invert the key value pairs of the dictionaries
> 2. Identify the common intersecting keys
> 3. Loop through the keys and check if their values match

The code could look something like below

```
dict_x = {v: k for k, v in dict_x.items()}
dict_y = {v: k for k, v in dict_y.items()}

for key in dict_x.keys() & dict_y.keys():
   print(key, dict_x[key])
   print(key, dict_y[key])
```

Here is the dict comprehension equivalent in python 3

```
result_set = {key: dict_x[key] for key in dict_x.keys() & dict_y.keys() if dict_x[key] == dict_y[key]}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because the items should have different keys based on the queries I used to form the dictionaries. I need to find which items have the same values regardless of their keys. If there is an item that whose vaule's don't exist in one dictionary I want to remove them.

Comment: are your values a tuple or list?

Comment: what if you have a row of values that are duplicate in the same table?

Comment: I was just trying to pull them straight from the dictionaries, so i think the answer is neither? maybe this is the step i'm missing...

Comment: how are you pulling them? you can do a type(dict[row]) on one of the rows to check it.

Comment: my query should have removed duplicates (in dict_y), so that's only a concern for dict_x.

Comment: what version of python?

Comment: you can invert the two dictionaries, so the tuple will now be the key and the current key will become the value. now you can do a set intersection on the tuples of both the dicts

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:/UserFolders/AnneGilligan/autoplots-2/atp-2.py", line 99, in <module>
    for key in lease_dict.keys() & reference_dict.keys():
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list'

.............
got this error when trying this method. I'm using python 2.7

Comment: try using set(lease_dict.keys()) & set(reference_dict.keys())

Comment: are you able to achieve the solution you expected?

Comment: i would like to add all all instances where the inverted keys are equal to a new dictionary

Comment: start with an empty dictionary d={} and start adding the key value pairs in the for loop. you could refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416131/python-add-new-item-to-dictionary

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> dict_a = {'a':[1,1,2,3]}
>>> dict_b = {'b':[1,2]}
>>> for a_key, b_key in zip(dict_a.keys(), dict_b.keys()):
...     print [i for i in dict_a[a_key] if i in set(dict_b[b_key])]
... 
[1, 1, 2]
```

Comment: will this disregard if the keys are different?

Comment: there is a problem with this answer. what if the columns have duplicate values?

Answer (score 0):

This will work as long as the elements in the array will always be in the same order.

```
dict_x = {'hi': ['hello', 'hi'], 'bye': ['good bye', 'bye']}
dict_y = {'hi': ['hello', 'hi']}
dict_z = dict()

for key, row in dict_x.items():
    if row in dict_y.values():
         dict_z[key] = row
print(dict_z)
```

If the elements won't be in the same order then you'll have to do this:

```
dict_x = {'hi': ['hi', 'hello'], 'bye': ['good bye', 'bye']}
dict_y = {'hi': ['hello', 'hi']}
dict_z = dict()

for x_key, x_row in dict_x.items():
    for y_key, y_row in dict_y.items():
        if set(x_row).intersection(y_row):
            dict_z[x_key] = y_row

print(dict_z)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help, it will return False if the dict is equal and true if not. I know its other way around

```
def compare_dict(
    dict_1: Dict[Any, Any], dict_2: Dict[Any, Any]
):
    new_key = any([False if key in dict_1 else True for key in dict_2])
    delete_key = any(
        [False if key in dict_2 else True for key in dict_1]
    )

    if new_key or delete_key:
        return True
    else:
        values_mismatch_flag = any(
            [
                True if v != dict_1[k] else False
                for k, v in dict_2.items()
            ]
        )
        if values_mismatch_flag:
            return True
        return False
```