# how to add just the values in key s1

Tags: python, dictionary

```
students={
1: {"pup1": "001", "s1": 10, "s2": 20},

2: {"pup2": "124", "s1": 20, "s2": 30},

3: {"pup3": "125", "s1": 30, "s2": 40}}
```

1. List item

Comment: your question seems incomplete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add new keys to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: Or [Python add new item to dictionary \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416131/python-add-new-item-to-dictionary)

Comment: I think the question is how to sum up the "s1" values from the dictionaries. The question is not clear at all.

Comment: To find the sum of the values of s1 across 3 dictionaries that is to add 10+20+30

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want to add all the values of s1, you need to iterate over the values() of dictionary students.

```
students={
    1: {"pup1": "001", "s1": 10, "s2": 20},

    2: {"pup2": "124", "s1": 20, "s2": 30},

    3: {"pup3": "125", "s1": 30, "s2": 40}}

sum1 = 0
for data in students.values():
    sum1 += data['s1']

avg = sum1 / len(students)

print(sum1)
print(avg)
```

Comment: Perhaps he meant to add values `in` the key `s1` not the `sum` of those values, separately.

Comment: @user5173426: PERHAPS!! Because the question is not clear as to what exactly the OP needs.

Comment: @ eiram_mahera:This is what i needed, also can you help me to find the average in similar fashion

Comment: @JacobNirappel: As this is what you were looking for please mark the answer correct.