# How to add a key and value using list and dict comprehension in list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries which is,

```
ip_list = [{'1403': [-56, -58], 'data': '1'},
           {'1403': [-56, -58], 'data': '0'}]
```

Now I need to add a new key(i.e., "mac") and value(i.e., "xyz") in a dictionary if dictionary contains 'data' = 1 and the outcome should be,

```
expected_outcome = [{'1403': [-56, -58], 'data': '1', 'mac':'xyz'},
                    {'1403': [-56, -58], 'data': '0'}]
```

I have tried with the,

```
list_dict_comp = [dict(item, **{'mac':'xyz'}) for item in ip_list]
```

Whereas, the above expression gives,

```
list_dict_comp = [{'1403': [-56, -58], 'data': '1', 'mac':'xyz'},
                  {'1403': [-56, -58], 'data': '0', 'mac':'xyz'}]
```

Can anyone help me out to achieve the **"expected_outcome"** using both list and dict comprehension together in a single expression?

Comment: This is not a problem you should solve with a list or dict comprehension. Just write a regular ol' loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you get

```
list_dict_comp = [{'1403': [-56, -58], 'data': '1', 'mac':'xyz'},
                  {'1403': [-56, -58], 'data': '0', 'mac':'xyz'}]
```

is because you are adding `{'mac':'xyz'}` to every element in the list.

Why not make your life easier and just iterate through ip_list, and add `{'mac':'xyz'}` if `data` is present in the keys of an element of ip_list, and the value for `data` is `'1'`

```
ip_list = [{'1403': [-56, -58], 'data': '1'},
           {'1403': [-56, -58], 'data': '0'}]

for ip in ip_list:
    if ip.get('data') == '1':
        ip['mac'] = 'xyz'
print(ip_list)
#[{'1403': [-56, -58], 'data': '1', 'mac': 'xyz'}, {'1403': [-56, -58], 'data': '0'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ip_list = [{'1403': [-56, -58], 'data': '1'},
           {'1403': [-56, -58], 'data': '0'}]
res = [dict(item, **{'mac':'xyz'}) if 'data' in item and item['data'] == '1' else item for item in ip_list]
print(res)
# [{'1403': [-56, -58], 'data': '1', 'mac': 'xyz'}, {'1403': [-56, -58], 'data': '0'}]
```

Comment: Provide some explanation to the code you write, so that next time if someone reads the solution, he knows what is happening

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh It's actually better without an explanation, because that makes it more obvious what an unreadable mess this really is. Hopefully people will avoid using this.

Comment: Agreed! A lot of times list comprehension is a pretty unreadable jumbled mess

Comment: `dict(item, **{'mac':'xyz'})` can be rewritten as `dict(item, mac='xyz')`

Comment: Also `if 'data' in item and item['data'] == '1'` can be shortened to `if item.get('data') == '1'`

Answer (score 1):

Use `list comprehensions` to solve this with the help of [`if-else`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406389/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension). You can add elements to the dictionary using [`update()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416131/python-add-new-item-to-dictionary) function  -

```
ip_list = [{'1403': [-56, -58], 'data': '1'}, {'1403': [-56, -58], 'data': '0'}]

[i.update({'mac': 'xyz'}) if i['data']=='1' else i for i in ip_list]         

print(ip_list)
     [{'1403': [-56, -58], 'data': '1', 'mac': 'xyz'},
      {'1403': [-56, -58], 'data': '0'}]
```

Comment: Don't use list comprehensions with side effects: [Is it Pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects)

Comment: @Georgy Thanks for bringing it to my notice.